# Azure resource throttling for Shared App Service pricing tier?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Is there a page explaining how this actually works? We're developing an API-only webservice and it's getting hit reasonably hard every day, but fairly consistently around mid-afternoon it starts spitting back "403 - Site Disabled". I'm *assuming* it's because we've exceeded the "4 CPU Hours per Day" quota you get for the shared pricing tier, but there's nothing unambiguously showing that this is the problem, and I'm struggling to understand what is the expected behaviour once you've exceeded this quota - obviously it doesn't shut itself down for 20 hours until your next 24 hour period starts, but at what point do you get full service availability? And surely there's some sort of chart or report I can get to confirm this is what's happening? Not even what's in the billing usage data makes much sense (it says 21-24 "shared app service hours" for most days).

Comment: "403 - Site Disabled" seems reasonably unambiguous to me! If you're using your quota then surely move to a basic SKU and move on? - aside from that, this question is off topic for Stack Overflow as it is not a programming question.

Comment: Well I don't *think* it's a programming question per se, but it's certainly a question that only programmers are going to understand, as you wouldn't be using the sharing pricing tier otherwise.

Comment: There is also the 5 minute limit, during which you are allowed to max out the CPU for 3 minutes

Comment: Yeah I found the "4hrs/day, 2.5 minutes of every 5" spec but again it's not clear what that means. After you've used up 4 hours of CPU time, what's the actual limitation until the 24 hour period elapses?

Comment: After the 4 hours, the website returns : `Error 403 - This web app is stopped` for the rest of the billing day. For the 5 minutes counter, it is stopped until the 5 minute window is over and will start again

Comment: I'm only getting "site disabled", nothing about stopped. I found the dashboard in the "classic" portal that shows usage info but it still doesn't give me a log or any historical info on when/if any quotas had been exceeded.